# Alternative to maybe for appending null to list

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to extract from a list only elements at odd positions.I know there are specific methods in Data.List but i am new and am trying to learn by reinventing the wheel.

So far i have tried this approach where i am branching the inner method

```
manF::[Int]->[Int]
manF []=[]
manF ls=go ls [] 0 where 
        go [] nl _ = nl
        go (x:xs) rez cnt=if cnt `mod`2 ==0 then go xs (x:rez) (cnt+1) else go xs rez (cnt+1)
```

But i would have to reverse this result at the end.

Is there anything more atomic then using maybe for dealing with null's

So if i move the **if clause** on the left side of the `cons` operator what can i return instead of null? I have tried Nothing,[] with no sucess.

```
manF::[Int]->[Int]
manF []=[]
manF ls=go ls [] 0 where 
        go [] nl _ = nl
        go (x:xs) rez cnt=if cnt `mod`2 ==0 then x else *(something?!)* : go xs rez (cnt+1)
```

Comment: If you work with an accumulator, like you do here, yes you have to reverse the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But i would have to reverse this result at the end.

If you work with an *accumulator*, the way you do here, yes you have to reverse the result. This also results in a problem in case you are processing an "infinite list", since in that case the recursion will never terminate, and you thus get stuck into an infinite loop (until you run out of memory).

> So if i move the if clause on the left side of the cons operator what can i return instead of null?

There is not really something like `null` (well there is `undefined`, but we would add that value to the head), nor will `Nothing` do the trick, since that is a *data constructor* for the `Maybe` type. You can use the empty list in case you want to terminate the sequence, but you can not fill in some "empty" in the head.

But in fact you do not need an inner method, nor do you need to coun the indices. You can use *pattern* matching for this:

```
manF :: [a] -> [a]
manF (x:_:xs) = x : manF xs
manF [x] = [x]
manF [] = []
```

Note that here the pattern is `(x:_:xs)` which is a compact form of `(x:(_:xs))`, so here we thus match a "cons" with `x` as head, and the tail should be a "cons" as well with as head `_` (a value we do not care about), and as tail `xs`. By doing so, we developed a means to make hops of two when iterating over the list.

The other clauses are base cases: for a singleton list we return that singleton list, and for the empty list, we return the empty list. We can merge the last two into one clause like:

```
manF :: [a] -> [a]
manF (x:_:xs) = x : manF xs
manF l = l
```

Note that due to lazyness, if we process an "infinite list", the algorithm will not get stuck into an infinite loop (of course given the generator of the source list does not go into an infinite loop), and we can thus use this to process "streams".

Another advantage is that our integer can never run into overflow (although for even-odd checks that would not make a difference, for a slightly different function, like for instance yield every *third* element, this could result in problems).

Comment: `manF [x] = [x]` -- wouldn't this mean that the last  element is added regardless of whether it is on an odd position in the list or not?

Comment: @andrybak: well since we make hops of two, it will not add the last element. For example if we process `manF [1,4]`, it will result in `1 : manF []`. In case we process a singleton list, like `[1]`, it will indeed result in `[1]`. but that is logically, since that is the *first* element (hence an odd index).

Comment: I do not understand the case for singleton list.Should i write in the matching  x=[x] or x=x ?I mean do you have to mach both e.g 5 -> [5] and  [5] ->[5] ?

Comment: When you pattern match with multiple "future elements" doesn't this mean that the list gets evaluated by chunks? Lets say (x:y:z:t) = ... Doesn't this mean that we pull 4 values from the list at every evaluation?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: the pattern of a singleton list is `(x:[])`, or if we use syntactical sugar, we use `[x]` in the head. `x` would mean we match the list, regardless of its value.

Comment: Understood ! Thank you !

Comment: @Bercovici Adrian: yes, we pull vour variables in that case (or three in the pattern matching in this answer) but the point is here that we *never* do duplicated work, since we make hops of two. We pull three values, but we use the first one, ignore the second, and recurse on the third one. As a result the number of recursion steps is lower, whereas the matching (that we have to do anyway), is still the same globally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168271/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 6):

Try mutual recursion. The standard demonstration of this is implementing `odd` and `even` in terms of each other:

```
odd, even :: Int -> Bool
odd 0 = False
odd n = not (even (n - 1))
even 0 = True
even n = not (odd (n - 1))
```

For `manF`, you might write

```
manF :: [Int] -> [Int]
manF = go_odd  where 
    go_odd [] = []
    go_odd (x:xs)  = x : go_even xs
    go_even [] = []
    go_even (x:xs) = go_odd xs
```